# how to use nested transitions with sass

Tags: html, css, sass, transition

I have this sass transitions:

```
      .card{
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
      }

      .artistInfo{display: none;}

      .card:hover{
        box-shadow: 10px 10px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.37);
        margin-top: -3%;
        .artistInfo{
          display: block;
        }
      }
```

the hovers works fine, and the transitions works too except for the .artistInfo transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animate display property. What you can do is animate opacity

```
.card {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.artistInfo {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.37);
  margin-top: -3%;
  &+.artistInfo {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMLvqZ

Comment: didnt work, its because im trying to make a transition from another element that has the hover

Comment: Is it next sibling element or a child of `.card`?

Comment: its the next element

Comment: i find this 
`.card{
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        .artistInfo{
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
      }
      
      .artistInfo{ opacity: 0;}
      
      .card:hover{
        box-shadow: 10px 10px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.37);
        margin-top: -3%;
        .artistInfo:hover{
          opacity: 1;

        }
      }`
and it works but im not shure if is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because "}" is in the incorrect place for ".card:hover"

**correct:**

```
.card{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

.artistInfo{display: none;}

.card:hover{
  box-shadow: 10px 10px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.37);
  margin-top: -3%;
}
.artistInfo{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: no, its in the right place, cause when i hover the .card the .artist should appear, and it works fine, but didnt work the transition in the display:block, only work the box shadow and the margin transition

Answer (score 0):

Your nesting is correct you just don't have a transition on your '.artistInfo' class. Updating to this should work:

```
.card{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

.artistInfo{
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}

.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.37);
    margin-top: -3%;
    .artistInfo{
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
        transition: all 0.5s ease
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working, i think the problem its because the nested .artistInfo dont have his own hover, and thats the way the transitions works but im still trying to fin the way

Comment: From memory you might not be able to transition on the display property. I've updated true above to that you transition the visible opacity property. Hope that works! Edit: you also might have to remove the display property, but I'm not sure if that will cause sizing issues on your HTML siblings without seeing the page